# How do I type numbers in vi?

Tags: macos, mac, unix, vi

Sometimes when I have to do basic editing of a file or write a basic script when I'm working in Terminal, I use `vi`. The problem is that when I type numbers, it goes to that line. Is there a way to turn this off or get around this? Surprisingly, when I searched Google and Super User, I couldn't find anything on this.

Comment: Did you tried to press "Insert" before entering numbers?

Comment: You might benefit from working through a vi tutorial [(example)](http://www.unix-manuals.com/tutorials/vi/vi-in-10-1.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get into insert mode by typing "i".

Comment: I am... (fifteen characters)

Comment: Are you perhaps using the numeric keypad without the Num Lock button pressed?

Comment: My keyboard has just the line of numbers on the top.

Comment: Use the command ":se showmode" (no quotes) and make sure you are in Insert mode (it will show -- INSERT --) at the bottom of the screen.